# Using Math.random

Tags: java, double

Very much a beginner here and trying to understand why I can't print a random double between 0 (inclusive) and 10 (exclusive) using a method that returns a double but that doesn't take any inputs.

```
package Practicing;

public class Practicing {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("The random double is:");
    }

    public static double getRandomNumber(){
        double random = Math.random()*10;
        System.out.print(random);
        return random;
    }

    public static void printer(double random){
        double value = random;
        System.out.print(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never calling the method `getRandomNumber()` in your `main()` method...

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You never call `getRandomNumber()` or `printer()`.

Comment: what about calling the ***getRandomNumber()*** method

Comment: Just call `getRandomNumber()` when you print on the `main` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method you wrote

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    double value = getRandomNumber();
    System.out.println("The random double is: "+value);
}
```

Additionally, you don't need the `printer` method.

## OR

You can do this:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    System.out.println("The random double is:");
    double value = getRandomNumber();
    printer(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @lara202 my pleasure